# Handling audio assets in Rails 3.2 with audio_* helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I'm trying to include audio files to the asset pipeline in my Rails 3.2 app and reference them with the help of the audio_* helper methods, but it doesn't work like I think it should work:

1. I have a audio file here:

   app/assets/audios/onturn.wav
2. I reference it in the view (HAML):

   %audio{ src: audio_path('onturn.wav'), id: 'on-turn-sound' }

which results in development to:

```
<audio id='on-turn-sound' src='/audios/onturn.wav'></audio>
```

and in production to:

```
<audio id='on-turn-sound' src='/audios/onturn-7728640b5d844c6b676d10f7572b6c8e.wav'></audio>
```

However, none of these files exist. Lets take a look at the resulting manifest.yml file:

```
onturn.wav: onturn-7728640b5d844c6b676d10f7572b6c8e.wav
onturn/index.wav: onturn-7728640b5d844c6b676d10f7572b6c8e.wav
```

So, only

```
public/assets/onturn.wav
public/assets/onturn-7728640b5d844c6b676d10f7572b6c8e.wav
```

exist.

If I put the file in public/audios manually and not in app/assets/audios, I get an error in production because the file is not precompiled, so the audio_path helper can't find it. If I put the file at both locations, it is also not found because no compiled version exists in public/audios but I don't get the error.

What is the clue with correct handling of audio and video files? CSS, JS and images are working fine, but audio and video does not work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

```
audio_tag 'onturn.wav'
```